# Cloud Function with Python triggered via Create event type of Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am using Cloud Functions with Python (Beta) to trigger the function when new item is added at `.../search/query/`

If I was doing the same in **Firebase** Cloud Functions (using Node.js) it will be trigger via following code:

```
functions.database.ref('.../search/query').onCreate((snapshot, context) => ...)`
```

Function will be triggered when `{'B': 'B'}` is added at `...search/query/` with following database tree:

```
...: {
    'search': {
          'query': {
              'A': 'A'
           }
    }
```

Assuming the similar approach for Python - I created Cloud Functions with Python which trigger using following:
[image: Google Cloud Functions Console]

**But** with Cloud Function in Python the function is trigger only when `.../search/query` is created but not triggered when a new item is added to `.../search/query/`

So how do I trigger function only when a new item is added at `.../search/query/` given I do not know the key of the new item that will be added?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the gcloud command you're using to create the trigger.

Comment: I am using google cloud console to set up triggers. @DougStevenson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by the [documentation for Database triggers paths](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#specify_the_database_instance_and_path), it sounds like you want a wildcard in the path:

```
.../search/query/{id}
```

Where `id` is a wildcard that will match when any new child is added under search/query.

Comment: Ooooo! Thank you! I remember I tried instead '${id}' from bad memory and out of sheer pain and I was getting an error. No wonder :/ Thank You very much :)))